# error in basic google map example

Tags: android, google-maps

I am Trying to show google map but it showing Infleting Error.......
java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.map_test/com.example.map_test.MainActivity}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

this is my Manifest file....

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map_test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map_test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBSQ2BV3QN5L8u4R08WHWzbNo_VYae7UQo" />
</application>
```

this is my XML file...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this my class file.....

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.map_test/com.example.map_test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
01-25 19:18:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: have you referenced google play services??

Comment: yes...i did.. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: Please format and post the complete stacktrace

Comment: @bhavdip still feel you have not referenced properly can u cross check once

Comment: @bhavdip pls post how you referenced google play services library project. looks like you have not done that properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out the compelte stacktrace is hard to say but I see some issues:

1) These permissions are not longer needed.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.map_test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map_test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

2) You are missing this inside `<application>`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

3) Please do not share your API key with the world

Comment: it's showing that..... Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/
 google_play_services_version').

Comment: Have you imported `google-play-services_lib` into your project?

Comment: It seems from you error that you are not importing it correctly.